# OpenGl how to move two circles

Tags: c++, opengl

I am new to OpenGl, right now my code can move a big circle with a small one inside him around the window.
Can you please tell me how to move the small circle separately from the big one, and also how to get him out from inside the big one.

And when for eg.: the small cirle is inside the big one when they are moving they moving together, and there is a line which is connects the center of the window with the small cirlce.

Here is my code:

```
    #include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include "glm/glm.hpp"

#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

#define PI 3.14159265359

using namespace std;

#define numVAOs 1

GLuint VBO;
GLuint VAO;

GLfloat radius = 0.2;
GLfloat centerx = 0.3;
GLfloat centery = 0;

GLfloat novX = 0.009;
GLfloat novY = 0.005;

GLdouble updateFrequency = 0.01, lastUpdate;

GLfloat s_vertices[600];

void updateVertexData()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        s_vertices[3 * i] = centerx + radius * cos(i * (2 * PI / 100));
        s_vertices[3 * i + 1] = centery + radius * sin(i * (2 * PI / 100));
        s_vertices[3 * i + 2] = 0;
    }

}

void updateVertexData1()
{

    for (int j = 100; j < 200; j++) {
        s_vertices[3 * j] = centerx + radius * (cos(j * (2 * PI / 100))) / 5;
        s_vertices[3 * j + 1] = centery + radius * (sin(j * (2 * PI / 100))) / 5;
        s_vertices[3 * j + 2] = 0;


    }
}


void updateVBO() {
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(s_vertices), s_vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}



GLuint renderingProgram;
GLuint vao[numVAOs];

bool checkOpenGLError() {
    bool foundError = false;
    int glErr = glGetError();
    while (glErr != GL_NO_ERROR) {
        cout << "glError: " << glErr << endl;
        foundError = true;
        glErr = glGetError();
    }
    return foundError;
}

void printShaderLog(GLuint shader) {
    int len = 0;
    int chWrittn = 0;
    char* log;
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &len);
    if (len > 0) {
        log = (char*)malloc(len);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, len, &chWrittn, log);
        cout << "Shader Info Log: " << log << endl;
        free(log);
    }
}

void printProgramLog(int prog) {
    int len = 0;
    int chWrittn = 0;
    char* log;
    glGetProgramiv(prog, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &len);
    if (len > 0) {
        log = (char*)malloc(len);
        glGetProgramInfoLog(prog, len, &chWrittn, log);
        cout << "Program Info Log: " << log << endl;
        free(log);
    }
}

string readShaderSource(const char* filePath) {
    string content;
    ifstream fileStream(filePath, ios::in);
    string line = "";

    while (!fileStream.eof()) {
        getline(fileStream, line);
        content.append(line + "\n");
    }
    fileStream.close();
    return content;
}

GLuint createShaderProgram() {

    GLint vertCompiled;
    GLint fragCompiled;
    GLint linked;

    string vertShaderStr = readShaderSource("vertexShader.glsl");
    string fragShaderStr = readShaderSource("fragmentShader.glsl");

    GLuint vShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint fShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    const char* vertShaderSrc = vertShaderStr.c_str();
    const char* fragShaderSrc = fragShaderStr.c_str();

    glShaderSource(vShader, 1, &vertShaderSrc, NULL);
    glShaderSource(fShader, 1, &fragShaderSrc, NULL);

    glCompileShader(vShader);
    checkOpenGLError();
    glGetShaderiv(vShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &vertCompiled);
    if (vertCompiled != 1) {
        cout << "vertex compilation failed" << endl;
        printShaderLog(vShader);
    }

    glCompileShader(fShader);
    checkOpenGLError();
    glGetShaderiv(vShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &fragCompiled);
    if (fragCompiled != 1) {
        cout << "fragment compilation failed" << endl;
        printShaderLog(fShader);
    }

    GLuint vfProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(vfProgram, vShader);
    glAttachShader(vfProgram, fShader);

    glLinkProgram(vfProgram);
    checkOpenGLError();
    glGetProgramiv(vfProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linked);
    if (linked != 1) {
        cout << "linking failed" << endl;
        printProgramLog(vfProgram);
    }

    glDeleteShader(vShader);
    glDeleteShader(fShader);

    return vfProgram;
}

void keyCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    if (action == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        switch (key) {
        case GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE:
            glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GLFW_TRUE);
            break;
        case GLFW_KEY_L:
            novX *= -1;
            break;
        case GLFW_KEY_R:
            radius += 0.01;
            updateVertexData();
            updateVertexData1();
            updateVBO();
            break;
        }
    }
}

void cursorPosCallback(GLFWwindow* window, double xPos, double yPos)
{

}

void mouseButtonCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int button, int action, int mods)
{

}

void init() {
    renderingProgram = createShaderProgram();

    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(s_vertices), s_vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

void cleanUpScene()
{
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glDeleteProgram(renderingProgram);
}

void display(GLFWwindow* window, double currentTime) {
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // fontos lehet minden egyes alkalommal törölni!
    glUseProgram(renderingProgram);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glPointSize(8.0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, 99);
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 100, 200);


    if (currentTime - lastUpdate >= updateFrequency) {
        centerx += novX;
        centery += novY;
        if (centerx + radius > 1 - abs(novX) || centerx - radius < -1 + abs(novX))
            novX *= -1;
        if (centery + radius > 1 - abs(novY) || centery - radius < -1 + abs(novY))
            novY *= -1;
        lastUpdate = currentTime;
        updateVertexData();
        updateVertexData1();
        updateVBO();
    }
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

int main(void) {
    updateVertexData();
    updateVertexData1();
    if (!glfwInit()) { exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(600, 600, "VAO VBO", NULL, NULL);

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keyCallback);

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) { exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    init();

    lastUpdate = glfwGetTime();

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        display(window, glfwGetTime());
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);

    cleanUpScene();

    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Read about [Uniform](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL)) and [Transformations](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Transformations).

Comment: @churill No. [Instancing](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Instancing) is not a solution for animating 2 meshes.